# C++ program runs but doesn't let the user enter all the information

Tags: c++

This is a program that I have been working on. I am just starting out in programming, so I am just trying to write simple programs for now. The ones I have done have worked great till this one. The program will run but it doesn't let the user enter all the information. I am not sure why. If someone could please help me understand. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double salary = 0.0;
    double wages = 0.0;
    float employee = 0;
    int hours;
    double total = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";
    cin >> employee; 

    cout << "Please enter the employee wages: $" << endl;
    cin >> wages;

    cout << "Please enter how many hours the employee worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    wages * hours == salary;

    cout << "The employee total earnings is $" << total << endl;

    cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks again for your time and help.

Here are the changes I have made but it's still not running right.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double salary = 0.0;
    double wages = 0.0;
    float employee = 0;
    int hours;
    double total = 0.0;

    cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";
    cin >> employee; 

    cout << "Please enter the employee wages: $" << endl;
    cin >> wages;

    cout << "Please enter how many hours the employee worked" << endl;
    cin >> hours;

    salary = wages * hours;

    cout << "The employee total earnings is $" << total << endl;

    cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";
    cin >> employee;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What information you can't input? Also you have a mistake 
   here: `wages * hours == salary;`, there should be only one `=` sign and the places should be reversed (`salary = wages * hours`)

Comment: Thanks for that information. It won't let the user input the wages or the hours. It will only let them enter the name.

Comment: What happens when you enter a name? Does it terminate, or does it simply not continue to the entry for wages, or does it ask to input wages, but doesn't allow the user to enter anything

Comment: It allows you to enter a name then when you hit enter for the next input it just skips the input and puts it all on the screen. Then it says to press any key to continue

Comment: What exactly you want to do here? its not clear... What are you want to acheive?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to put sample text of what running this code looks like?

Answer (score 5):

You have employee set as a `float`. I'm assuming that you mean an employee name, so you want to have a string there.

The simple explanation is that `cin` breaks when it's expecting a number and you give it a string. And by "breaks" I mean that subsequent `cin`s, especially ones that expect numbers, get swallowed up in a blur of nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
wages * hours == salary;
```

is meaningless (i'm not even exactly sure what it does). You probably wanted to calculate the salary, but that should be something like

```
salary = wages * hours;
```

You also never calculate your `total` variable - it's always 0.

Comment: not to mention the `total` variable is never assigned a value when he attempts to output it

Comment: @DanF it's 0.0, up at the declaration block.

Comment: Well, I assume that its supposed to be some calculated value

Answer (score 1):

```
    cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";

    system("pause");

    return 0;
```

Is your problem here? Because you aren't asking for input here, which could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "All the information." My guess is that you're trying to enter a first and last name for the employee name, and it's skipping some inputs. The reason for this is that `cin` (somewhat unintuitively) splits input up by whitespace. That means that it treats each string, number, lump of characters, etc (referred to as "tokens") as a separate cin object, even if you enter more than one and press enter.

So, if you see this:

Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit

and enter "John Doe," it will store "John" to employee, print "Please enter the employee wages: $," and then *immediately* store "Doe" to wages, without prompting for input, because "Doe" is still waiting to be stored This is one of the first C++ "gotcha!"s that beginners experience, and there are many ways around it. One of them is to use `cin.getline(...)`. Another is to use `cin >> noskipws >> employee;`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/

Obviously, storing a word to a `float` has issues of its own, but I assume you're handling that separately. If you want to store a string, look into std::string.

Comment: I am only entering a first name not a last

Comment: I am not sure of how to do strings

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop. One that runs until the employee name is equal to "-1".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but maybe you want something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   double salary = 0.0;
   double wages = 0.0;
   String employee = "";
   int hours = 0;
   double total = 0.0;

   cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";
   cin >> employee; 

   cout << "Please enter the employee wages: $" << endl;
   cin >> wages;

   cout << "Please enter how many hours the employee worked" << endl;
   cin >> hours;

   salary = wages * hours;

   cout << "The employee total earnings is $" << total << endl;

   cout << "Please enter an employee name or -1 to quit";

   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

If you want validation on the employee name, you need `while` loop on the input employe untill the user insert some token.